# Pattern matching nested tuples in ocaml

Tags: recursion, pattern-matching, ocaml

I'm trying to recursively go through  a nested list of files and folders. While I do that I want to print the names of files and folders I visit, but I am doing something very wrong. This is what I have:

```
type 'a fileTree =¬
  | File of 'a¬
  | Folder of 'a * ('a fileTree list)

let printFiles tree =
  let rec visit tree = function
    | [] -> print_string "Done"
    | File f :: t -> visit t
    | Folder (name, contents) :: t -> visit contents
  in
  visit tree
```

Doing that I get

```
Error: This expression has type 'a fileTree list -> unit but an expression was expected of type unit
```

for line `(File f :: t -> visit t)`.

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT 1**

The code is now

```
let printFiles tree =
  let rec visit = function
    | File file -> Printf.printf "file: %s\n" file
    | Folder (name, contents) ->
      Printf.printf "folder: %s\n" name;
      List.iter visit contents
  in
  List.iter visit tree
```

But I still get this error for the last line:

```
Error: This function has type ('a -> unit) -> 'a list -> unit
   It is applied to too many arguments; maybe you forgot a `;'
```

Answer (score 1):

You forget parenthesis here:

```
print_string "File " ^ f
```

it is evaluated as `(print_string "File ") ^ f`, but what you're expecting is

```
print_string ("File " ^ f)
```

The same is with `"Folder"` case.

### Update

In the updated example, you have a function of two arguments applied to one. I suppose, that instead of:

```
 let rec visit tree = function
```

You want to write

```
 let rec visit = function
```

which is equivalent to

```
 let rec visit tree = match tree with
```

Comment: Thanks, that's true but it doesn't solve the whole problem. I've updated the example with a simplified version that still gives some trouble.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you've written `visit` as a function over lists but called it on a file tree.

Let's change it to a function over trees and use `List.iter` to travese lists:

```
let print_files tree =
  let rec visit = function
    | File file -> 
      Printf.printf "file: %s\n" file
    | Folder (name, contents) ->
      Printf.printf "folder: %s\n" name;
      List.iter visit contents in
  visit tree
```

Comment: Thanks, but now it gives me

`Error: This function has type string fileTree -> unit
       It is applied to too many arguments; maybe you forgot a ';'.`

Answer (score 0):

I solved it in the following way in the end:

```
let writeFilesFromTree tree =
  let rec visit = function
    | [] -> print_string "-\n"
    | File f :: t -> Printf.printf "file: %s\n" f ; visit t
    | Folder (name, contents) :: t ->
      Printf.printf "name: %s\n" name ;
      visit contents ;
      visit t in
  visit tree;;
```

It still doesn't feel like an optimal solution at all, and I have the feeling I am sabotaging tail recursion with the last two consecutive calls to `visit`.